# Message: Unexpected element 'context-root' encountered , Unable to deploy on jboss 7.3.10 | Default context root configuration on jboss-web.xml

Tags: maven, jboss, war, contextroot, jboss-web

Without context root tag, able to deploy on jboss server 7.3.10 and able to access application with default context root

War File Application

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>MyApp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

With context root tag , getting below exception

```
10:54:28,163 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."UtxQVAClient-1.0.0.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."UtxQVAClient-1.0.0.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "UtxClient-1.0.0.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0027: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/C:/Users/Applications/jboss-eap-7.3.10/jboss-eap-7.3/standalone/deployments/UtxClient-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/web.xml" at [3,5]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more
**Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,5]
Message: Unexpected element 'context-root' encountered**
    at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:115)
    at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.WebMetaDataParser.parse(WebMetaDataParser.java:196)
    at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.WebMetaDataParser.parse(WebMetaDataParser.java:51)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:96)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration shouldn't be in a "web.xml" file but in a jboss-web.xml file as it is jboss specific.

Comment: Added only in jboss-web.xml only.

Comment: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/C:/Users/Applications/jboss-eap-7.3.10/jboss-eap-7.3/standalone/deployments/UtxClient-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/web.xml" ... Message: Unexpected element 'context-root'  disagrees with your statement